# create a new collection from existing collection's object array type field in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, import, collections, export

I would like create a new collection from an existing collection.
The structure of document is like this.

```
{"_id" : "ObjectId('1234')",
  "field2" : "value2",
  "field3" : [
        {"field3-1": "value3", 
         "field3-2":"value4", 
         "field3-3":"value5", 
         "field3-4":"value6"},
         {"field3-1": "value7", 
         "field3-2":"value8", 
         "field3-3":"value9", 
         "field3-4":"value10"}
    ]
}
```

I would like a new collection that has field3-1, field3-2, field3-3 and field3-4 like the following.

```
{
    "source_id": "1234",
    "field3-1": "value3",
    "field3-2":"value4", 
    "field3-3":"value5", 
    "field3-4":"value6"
},
{
    "source_id": "1234",
    "field3-1": "value7", 
    "field3-2":"value8", 
    "field3-3":"value9", 
    "field3-4":"value10"
}
```

I tried using export by choosing only field3, it created the file like the following when I selected the type as csv, which I can't export into any collection.

```
"[
"{
    ""field3-1"": ""value3"",
    ""field3-2"":""value4"", 
    ""field3-3"":""value5"", 
    ""field3-4"":""value6""
}",
"{
    ""field3-1"": ""value7"",
    ""field3-2"":""value8"", 
    ""field3-3"":""value9"", 
    ""field3-4"":""value10""
}"
]"
```

I have almost 20 million documents in the existing collection, what could be the efficient way to achieve it? If anyone has an experience, could you give some advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do an `$unwind`. `$replaceRoot` to move the sub-documents to root level. `$out` to a new collection.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$field3"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$field3",
          {
            // fields you want to keep
            "source_id": "$_id"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$out": {
      "db": "output-db",
      "coll": "output-collection"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_1hCQ6zG72a)

Comment: Hi @ray, if I want to keep _id from the source collection, how I could achieve it?

Comment: @AnnaLee updated the answer to use `$mergeObjects`.